# The flag of system function open() :O_DIRECT undecleared when I compile the code

Tags: c, linux, system

but when I add #define _ _USE_GNU 1 it works,I wonder why it works? and why I only add the header <fcntl.h> it does not work? I am a primer in Linux programming, and where I can learn such konwloage, thanks a lot!

I add #define //#define __USE_GNU 1, and it works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqZdJ.png)

Comment: ["O_DIRECT, O_NOATIME, O_PATH, and O_TMPFILE flags are Linux-
       specific.  One must define _GNU_SOURCE to obtain their
       definitions."](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) . Presumably contrasted to other flavors of POSIX.

Comment: Note you have to `#define` those feature request macros *before* any `#include` lines.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

The `<fcntl.h>` header you are using has been designed to be used with C source code written for different standards that can be selected at compile time.

The POSIX standard does not specify an `O_DIRECT` identifier, so source code written just for POSIX is allowed to use an `O_DIRECT` identifier for its own purposes. If `<fcntl.h>` defined an `O_DIRECT` identifier, it could cause an error when this source code using `O_DIRECT` for its own purposes is compiled or, worse, could cause the program to function incorrectly. To avoid this, by default, `<fcntl.h>` does not define `O_DIRECT`, and it must be requested by the program.

GNU/Linux provides additional features beyond the POSIX standard, including the `O_DIRECT` identifier. To use these features, source code should have `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before `#include <fcntl.h>`. This preprocessor macro indicates to `<fcntl.h>` that it should provide the GNU/Linux additional features, not just the POSIX features.

The header uses preprocessor conditional directives such as `#if` to select what it declares and defines. When `_GNU_SOURCE` and other feature test macros are not defined, it declares and defines only the features specified by the POSIX standard. When `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined, the header declares and defines additional features.

`__USE_GNU` is a macro name intended for internal use in the headers. You should not define it directly. The headers examine the various specified [feature test macros](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) such as `_BSD_SOURCE`, `_XOPEN_SOURCE`, and `_GNU_SOURCE` to determine what to do, and they may set internal macros such as `__USE_GNU` as a part of how they manage the decisions. By setting `__USE_GNU`, you appear to have triggered definition of `O_DIRECT`. However, you should not use that macro to do it. Use only the feature test macros specified in the documentation.

Comment: Just a little note to why setting `__USE_GNU` isn't portable, but `_GNU_SOURCE` is: some of the BSDs use `__GNU_VISIBLE` instead of `__USE_GNU`, and some other unix-derivatives don't use any of these extra macros at all, but directly check for `defined(_GNU_SOURCE)` in headers -- so always use the officially documented feature macros.